# ms-access-2010 returns #func[exclamation mark]

Tags: sql, ms-access-2010

I have a sql-statement which includes a switch, i want to execute on ms-access-2010.

sql:

```
SELECT 
TABLE_1.ID, 
SWITCH
(
    (TABLE_3.ID IN (7,8) AND TABLE_1.SOME_COLUMN = 2), (SELECT MAX(TABLE_4.ID) FROM TABLE_4 WHERE  TABLE_4.TABLE_2_ID = TABLE_2.ID),
    (SELECT MIN(TABLE_4.SOME_COLUMN) FROM TABLE_4 WHERE TABLE_4.TBL_2_ID = TABLE_1.TBL_2_ID)
)AS SOME_ALIAS 
FROM 
    ((TABLE_1 
        LEFT JOIN TABLE_2 ON TABLE_1.TABLE_2_ID = TABLE_2.ID)
        LEFT JOIN TABLE_3 ON TABLE_2.TABLE_3_ID = TABLE_3.ID)
```

In my result, the column 'some_column' is always `#Function!`

If i do not use the switch-statement and add the sub-selects from the two cases as normal selected-fields like this:

```
SELECT 
TABLE_1.ID, 
(SELECT MAX(TABLE_4.ID) FROM TABLE_4 WHERE  TABLE_4.TABLE_2_ID = TABLE_2.ID) AS SOME_COLUMN_1,
(SELECT MIN(TABLE_4.SOME_COLUMN) FROM TABLE_4 WHERE TABLE_4.TBL_2_ID = TABLE_1.TBL_2_ID) AS SOME_COLUMN_2
FROM 
    ((TABLE_1 
        LEFT JOIN TABLE_2 ON TABLE_1.TABLE_2_ID = TABLE_2.ID)
        LEFT JOIN TABLE_3 ON TABLE_2.TABLE_3_ID = TABLE_3.ID)
```

i don't get any problems (There are only a couple of rows where there is no value inside of SOME_COLUMN_1 AND SOME_COLUMN_2).

What is causing the result of `#FUNCTION!` here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Switch` statement requires an even number of arguments. You're only passing 3 arguments, thus causing an error.

You can either use `IIF`, or add an additional comparison argument (Perhaps just `True` as 3rd argument if you want to return the last argument if the first one isn't true).

```
SELECT 
TABLE_1.ID, 
IIF
(
    (TABLE_3.ID IN (7,8) AND TABLE_1.SOME_COLUMN = 2), (SELECT MAX(TABLE_4.ID) FROM TABLE_4 WHERE  TABLE_4.TABLE_2_ID = TABLE_2.ID),
    (SELECT MIN(TABLE_4.SOME_COLUMN) FROM TABLE_4 WHERE TABLE_4.TBL_2_ID = TABLE_1.TBL_2_ID)
)AS SOME_ALIAS 
FROM 
    ((TABLE_1 
        LEFT JOIN TABLE_2 ON TABLE_1.TABLE_2_ID = TABLE_2.ID)
        LEFT JOIN TABLE_3 ON TABLE_2.TABLE_3_ID = TABLE_3.ID)
```